# Can (and when) split brain occur on failover cluster with 2 nodes and disk witness?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, iscsi, failovercluster

we have a two node cluster with a shared disk quorum (iscsi).
we are experiencing every now and again failures that are resulting in downtime.

In the logs we see the 'conflict IP' on the shared ip, supposedly pointing to a split-brain between the two nodes.

I wasn't able to find any documentation explaining how this can happen. on the contrary all documentation I found explains exactly how my setup (2nodes+disk witness) prevents exactly this from happening.

Comment: What application are you trying to cluster?

Comment: its an internally developed application. set up as a generic service..

Comment: What is running the application? IIS?

Comment: No. Its an exe running a windows service